# Rails 4 Ignore Error/Exception and Continue

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, exception

Sorry if it's an easy question, I am pretty new to Ruby.

When users sign up, or login I would like to keep statistics with Redis

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    $redis.hincrby("2016MMDD", "new_users", 1)
    render json: @user
  end
end
```

If for any reason $redis.hincrby fails, is there a way to continue the execution of the code and render the user anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just wrap the risky code in a begin/rescue/end block that captures the issue and continues execution.

http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_exceptions.html. - see handling exceptions.

You might want to research what exceptions to look for, say if redis has gone away, rather than the base Exception catch